# Programmatically put an Android activity in its "Stopped" state, without destroying it?

Tags: android, android-activity, activity-lifecycle

I'm creating a music app in Android with a background service playing the music, and a Home activity that has various fragments and is the UI of the app.

When I press the **home button**  on my phone, this app gets put in the background of course, and the lifecycle methods get called down to onStop(), in which the UI gets disconnected from the Service in order to allow background playback, the user can keep using their device and do other things. When I get back to my UI Activity, onStart gets called and the UI and Service reconnect together, giving me back controls over the music. onStart gets me **the same activity** in the foreground, **it doesn't create another instance of the same activity**.

I'm trying to implement also a function for when I press the **back button**  on my device, so the UI activity can have the same behavior as with the home button, i.e. simply put the UI in the background (onStop). Instead, the default behavior of the back button is to finish(), killing the current activity it's called from (thus calling onDestroy).

What could I do for that? Couldn't really find anything online. Seems such a simple function that every music app has (not killing the app when pressing back, but just send it into background)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override `onBackPressed` and move the Activity Task to back. Based on the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#moveTaskToBack%28boolean%29) Activity'r order in the Task will also remain unchanged:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    this.moveTaskToBack(true);
}
```

Comment: would that keep that instance of the activity running? (and all the fragments inside it). I'm going to give it a try now

Comment: It should behave as if `onStop()` is called

Comment: That was precisely what I was looking for. Thank you

Comment: Great! Enjoy coding